# Keyboard command binding on WPF Inside User Control

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I am trying witth the following code for keyboard command binding on WPF window:

```
  RoutedCommand cmndSettings = new RoutedCommand();
  cmndSettings.InputGestures.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.S, ModifierKeys.Alt));
  CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(cmndSettings, mnuSettings_Click));

  private void mnuSettings_Click(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      MessageBox.Show("key pressed");
  }
```

This is working **fine** if I place this code inside a xaml Window's cs file. But, if I place it inside a user control's cs file, which dynamically loaded in a parent window, **keyboard events aren't triggering** there at all. **What I need to do to get it working inside a user control plz?** Thanks.

Comment: Is the UserControl focusable? Have you checked that it really has the focus? Try setting the focus, when clicking on it or loading it.

Comment: oh, yes. this is what was wrong. Thanks for figuring out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work with controls under a user control, its very important that, the containers/user control is focus-able properly. otherwise, may not work.